# Reading data from a SharePoint list into R

Tags: r, sharepoint

I need to read in data from a SharePoint site into R for an analysis I am running.

The data is stored in a list on the SharePoint site but I am having difficulty connecting to the data.

First of all I don't believe I am passing the correct URL, I have tried chopping various bits off the URL but I still get a 401 error.

The URL I paste into the browser looks as follows:

```
https://mycompanynameazure.sharepoint.com/sites/programName/Project_CAP/Lists/SGP%20SP%20Intake%20Form/AllItems.aspx?e=3%3AV0Fs0i&at=9
```

I've tried the following code but as I said I get a list back but buried in the list is a 401 error

```
URL <- "https://mycompanynameazure.sharepoint.com/sites/programName/Project_CAP/Lists/SGP%20SP%20Intake%20Form/AllItems.aspx"

r <- GET(URL,authenticate("myName","password",type = "any"))
```

I have created a power automate flow to save the list as a CSV to a OneDrive but unfortunately I have the same issue connecting to the file there:

```
x <- read.csv(file = "https://mycompanyazure-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/my_name_my_company_com/EZN8zEwOuUVJmr0LAPmXpvwBB_oYWWgPDGRp2hMKXtkjKQ?e=XNVwfF")

Error in file(file, "rt") : 
  cannot open the connection to 'https://mycompanyazure-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/My_name_my_company_com/EZN8zEwOuUVJmr0LAPmXpvwBB_oYWWgPDGRp2hMKXtkjKQ?e=XNVwfF'
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open URL 'https://mycompanyazure-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/my_name_my_company_com/EZN8zEwOuUVJmr0LAPmXpvwBB_oYWWgPDGRp2hMKXtkjKQ?e=XNVwfF': HTTP status was '401 Unauthorized'
```

Unfortunately for me my company prevents power automate flows saving files to network drives as this would be easy as RStudio Server has a mount to this network drive.

Comment: @akrun unfortunately I am using the correct URL :(

Comment: Can you try `library(data.table);file<-  getURL(URL, userpwd="myName:password", ssl.verifypeer=FALSE);

dt<- fread(file)`

Comment: The contents of `file` are an empty character string i.e. `""`

Comment: I generally use this to extract from url. Maybe it is a bit different for your url. Sorry, can't test it without example

Comment: @akrun no worries thanks for trying. I have raised a ticket with IT, maybe there's some regulatory/permissions etc. issue. Thanks again.